# What kind of function is $a(x)^{b(x)}$?

Tags: functions, extension-field

What kind of function is $a(x)^{b(x)}$, where $a(x), b(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$, and what field of functions does it "live" in?  What if $a(x), b(x) \in \mathbb R(x)$?

- Certainly in neither case do we have a rational function, i.e. $a(x)^{b(x)}$ is not an element of $\mathbb R(x)$.
- It is also (I think?) not an algebraic function, i.e. it does not live in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb R(x)$.

Do such things have a name?  And is there a name for the field of functions "like" this (whatever that means)?

(I realize that last question is fairly vague, as I'm not sure what exactly I mean by "like" this.  I guess I'm looking for a name for a class of functions and partial functions that continues the sequence $\textbf{Polynomial}, \textbf{Rational}, \textbf{Algebraic}, \dots...$)

Comment: There are a lot of rings and fields of analytic functions, here you have one whose elements have finitely many branch points (at the zeros of $a(x)$) so the first thing is to clarify those branches, not confusing $a(x)^{1/2}$ with $-a(x)^{1/2}$ nor $e^{b(x) \log a(x)}$ with $e^{b(x) (2i\pi +\log a(x))}$. The latter is not rational nor algebraic over $\Bbb{R}(x)$. The next thing is to ask a transcendental basis (a minimal set generating your ring or field over $\Bbb{R}(x)$)

Comment: To really make them *functions* you'd need to exclude points where $a(x)$ becomes negative or vanishes, from their domains.